# Python 3 recognized an element as a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm defining a loss function `L(X,Y,c,b,d)`, where X and Y should be arrays, and c, b, d are floats. Here are my codes:

```
def L(X,Y,c,b,d):
    error=0
    a=Y[0]
    for i in range(len(X)):
        error = error + ((c*X[i]+(a/b)*np.sqrt(b**2-X[i]**2)+d)-Y[i])**2
    return error
```

I'm getting

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'",
```

which seems to mean that python recognized X[i] as a string. What should I do?

Here are the full code, and X is a column of numbers.

```
def L(X,Y,c,b,d):
     error=0
     a=Y[0]
     for i in range(len(X)):
         error = error + ((c*X[i]+(a/b)*np.sqrt(b**2-X[i]**2)+d)-Y[i])**2
     return error               

def L_prime_c(X,Y,c,b,d):
    p=0
    for i in range(len(X)):
        p=p+2*L(X,Y,c,b,d)*X[i]
    return p
def L_prime_d(X,Y,c,b,d):
    r=0
    for i in range(len(X)):
        r=r+2*L(X,Y,c,b,d)
    return r
def fit(X,Y,learning_rate=1e-3,max_iter=20000,epsilon=1e-5):
    c=1
    b=1
    d=Y[0]
    for i in range(max_iter):
        gradient_c = L_prime_c(X,Y,c,b,d)
        c_new = c - learning_rate * gradient_c
        gradient_b = L_prime_b(X,Y,c,b,d)
        b_new = b - learning_rate * gradient_b
        gradient_d = L_prime_d(X,Y,c,b,d)
        d_new = d - learning_rate * gradient_d  
        if np.abs(c_new - c) < epsilon and np.abs(d_new - d) < epsilon and np.abs(b_new - b) < epsilon:
            break
        c=c_new
        b=b_new        
        d=d_new
    return np.array([c,b,d])

#getting X, Y
In = xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\gris_\Desktop\calculation4.xlsx')
isheet = In.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
X=isheet.col_values(0)
Y=isheet.col_values(1)
a=Y[0]

#Calculation & Output
result=fit(X,Y,learning_rate=1e-3,max_iter=20000,epsilon=1e-5)
```

Problem solved: I have 6 columns of different length, so when reading data from one column, python actually adds these " to make shorter ones the same length as the longest one. When I delete the other columns, things work out fine. Many thanks for your help! :D

Comment: What does X contain?

Comment: do you have a sample input?

Comment: I import X after defining this function, and it is an array of floats.

Comment: Should I define X before defining this fuction?

Comment: You should make sure that your `X` (and `Y`) lists contain only number elements (or at least elements that support arithmetic operands), as it stands now `X` contains strings which is what Python complains about (i.e. doesn't know how to rise a string to a power of two in your case).

Comment: Please add the call of the function containing the values you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the code you just added, try to rewrite X,Y like this:

```
X=list(map(float,isheet.col_values(0)))
Y=list(map(float,isheet.col_values(1)))
```

Another: Your function can be simplified as a sum of all errors instead.

```
import numpy as np

# Another way of writing it
#def L(X,Y,c,b,d):
#    error=0
#    a=Y[0]
#    for x,y in zip(X,Y):
#        error += ((c*x+(a/b)*np.sqrt(b**2-x**2)+d)-y)**2
#    return error

# Or even better:
def L(X,Y,c,b,d):
    a = Y[0]
    error = sum(((c*x+(a/b)*np.sqrt(b**2-x**2)+d)-y)**2 for x,y in zip(X,Y))
    return error

X = [2.2,2.2,3.2]
Y = [2.0,2.1,3.1]
c = 1
b = 20
d = 1

print(L(X,Y,c,b,d))
```

Returns: `29.148285465180138`

Where as, chaning X and Y to:

```
X = [2.2,2.2,3.2,'a']
Y = [2.0,2.1,3.1,'b']
```

Returns: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed a lot conciser than my own codes!

Comment: I modified my codes as you said, but I'm getting "ValueError: could not convert string to float". So I checked my excel workbook, it really is a 49*1 matrix of numbers...

Comment: @GrisNX just print(X) without doing the conversion and post it here!

Comment: That's a great move! I don't know what caused this problem but here it is: [595.703, ***some more numbers***, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

Comment: I think I have found the answer: I have 6 columns of different length, so when reading data from one column, python actually adds these " to make shorter ones the same length as the longest one. When I delete the other columns, things work out fine.

Comment: @GrisNX Don't say that. I think you solved this problem yourself with some guidance. Good luck in the future!